# SSRS - Count total numbers of each categorie within same column

Tags: reporting-services, count, expression

Is there a certain way an expression can be written in SSRS which counts how many times a certain product occurs in one column?

Table
Table
Table
Chair
Chair
Cup
Chair
Chair

So at the end we can have something that displays
Table: 3
Chair: 4
Cup: 1

I do want to mention though, that I don't want to hardcode the values to be counted, (Chair, Cup, Table).

The report should look like the below having the Summary Section and below (what I already have is the actual report)

[image: E.g.]

Thank you

Comment: Add a tablix, add a row group that groups on the column you are interested in, add an expression something like =countrows() to count the values

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just group by product and sum?

This is the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/lesson-6-adding-grouping-and-totals-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: So what I am trying to get is, more like a summary than listing all the items and the total below.

I have updated my original post above how the report currently looks like and where the summary section should go

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to update that i was able to somewhat accomplish what was needed using the Table Wizard.

To count the rows, I used the following expression: =count(Fields!Item_Types.Value) it did however require me to have all the parts listed again to perform a count. For now, I just contracted / hid all those rows.

[image]